# Reversible vs irreversible operators in stochastic transport theory

Tags: statistical-mechanics, stochastic-processes

The particle in a potential driven by a fluctuating Gaussian white noise force $\Gamma(t)$ has equation of motion
$$ \dot{v} = -\gamma v +f(x) +\Gamma(t)  $$
and its probability $P(x,v,t)$ to have position $x$ and velocity $v$ is described by the Kramers equation
$$ \partial_t P(x,v,t) = L_K P(x,v,t), $$
where
$$L_K = -\partial_x v + \partial_v [\gamma v - f(x)] + \gamma \sqrt{kT/m} \partial_v^2.$$
is the "Kramers Operator".

The textbooks (Risken 1989 for example) identify "reversible" and "irreversible" components of this operator. The reversible part is written as
$$L_r = -v \partial_x  - f(x)\partial_v $$
while the irreversible part is
$$ L_{ir} = \gamma \partial_v[v + \sqrt{kT/m}\partial_v].$$

My question is this: what is "reversible" here? What is the reversal operation which $L_r$ satisifies and $L_{ir}$ doesn't? Is it $t \rightarrow -t$? Or is it $t \rightarrow -t$ as $x \rightarrow -x$ and $v \rightarrow -v$? What is irreversible about the "irreversible operator"? Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: Odd derivatives are usually time-reversible while even powers are time-irreversible (e.g., diffusion is a second order derivative and irreversible while dispersion is a third order and reversible).  I leave this as a comment because I don't recall off hand why this is the case...